# Change Flutter Drawer corner radius

Tags: flutter

I am using Drawer with a BottomAppBar. When I click the menu icon it shows the Drawer. I want to change the top left and top right corner radius of Flutter Drawer. Is it possible to customize the corner radius?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution. Just have to add canvasColor: Colors.transparent to the MaterialApp theme and it will work.

Answer (score 36):

Drawer in Flutter already have a shape property which can be used to change the shape of drawer. Below is the code to change corner radius of Drawer:

```
         Drawer(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
            child: .....
          ),
```

There is no need of wrapping drawer around any widget.

Answer (score 25):

You can try to wrap `Drawer` in `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(4.0)),
  child: Drawer(...),
)
```

Comment: It's working but the background is White, not transparent.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you should behave.

```
 drawer: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(35), bottomRight: Radius.circular(35)),
      child: Drawer(...),),
```

Comment: To remove duplication in `BorderRadius` creation from your example, it could be creted with next constructor `BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(35))`.